# Loss of CSS class after style update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am applying a class (rShift) to a DIV that acts as a menu tab. The class gives it a `:hover` behaviour. On clicking the DIV, I bring in a menu on to the screen. On collapsing the menu, I loose the class and the `:hover` behaviour too.

I am using jQuery UI and have even tried `.addClass('')` to apply the lost class, but it did not work.

See it at: http://pastebin.com/hdb8Y2Ke | http://bharath.lohray.com/ftree/

When the page is initially loaded, you can see a tab at the top left corner of the page, just under the search box. On hovering the mouse it jumps out a few pixels. On clicking, the menu appears. On clicking the tab again, the menu collapses and the jump out effect is lost :-(.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is being added, but on click, you are applying an inline style to the leftmenutab directly via jquery.  This style (left) overrides any styles you have in your style sheets.

I would remove the inline styles you are applying via jquery and add the styles you want to your css.

Create styles like this:

```
.leftMenuTab[data-state="expanded"] { left: 100px; }
.leftMenuTab[data-state="collapsed"] { left: 0; }
```

and remove these lines from your javascript:

```
$(".leftMenuTab").css("left", "+=100px");
$(".leftMenuTab").css("left", "-=100px");
```

Alternatively, add and remove classes from your leftMenuTab and leftMenu on click and style them through CSS.  Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="leftMenu">Hello Menu</div>
<div class="leftMenuTab" data-state="collapsed">
<span class="charIcon"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.leftMenuTab').click(function(e) {
  $('.leftMenuTab,.leftMenu').toggleClass('expanded');
}
```

CSS:

```
.leftMenuTab .charIcon:after{
  content:'>>';
}

.leftMenuTab.expanded .charIcon:after{
  content:'<<';
}
.leftMenuTab {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    top: 45px;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: -10px;
}
.leftMenuTab:hover {left:0;}
.leftMenuTab.expanded { left:100px;}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution :-) I wish I could choose multiple correct answers. I was just beginning to suspect that the inline styles had something to do with it. :-)

Comment: I think you'll find this solution is a bit cleaner, and follows best practices in separating out code, markup, and styles into their proper places.

Comment: +1 I see you improved your answer a lot. I just went for quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

After you modify the style of the element, the style `left: 0px;` is left in the DIV, this neglated the effect of the hover.

This is the relevant code:

```
$('.leftMenuTab').click(function(e) {
    temp = $(this);
    if ($('.leftMenuTab').attr('data-state') == "collapsed") {
        $(".charIcon", this).html("&laquo;");
        $('.leftMenuTab').attr('data-state', 'expanded');
        $(".leftMenu").css("left", "+=110px");
        $(".leftMenuTab").css("left", "+=100px");
    } else {
        $(".charIcon", this).html("&raquo;");
        $('.leftMenuTab').attr('data-state', 'collapsed');
        $(".leftMenu").css("left", "-=110px");
        $(".leftMenuTab").css("left", "-=100px");
        $(this).addClass("rShift");
    }
});
```

The quickest fix is to erase the `left` style instead of modyfing it (and you don't need to add the class again):

```
$('.leftMenuTab').click(function(e) {
    temp = $(this);
    if ($('.leftMenuTab').attr('data-state') == "collapsed") {
        $(".charIcon", this).html("&laquo;");
        $('.leftMenuTab').attr('data-state', 'expanded');
        $(".leftMenu").css("left", "+=110px");
        $(".leftMenuTab").css("left", "+=100px");
    } else {
        $(".charIcon", this).html("&raquo;");
        $('.leftMenuTab').attr('data-state', 'collapsed');
        $(".leftMenu").css("left", ""); //set to empty string
        $(".leftMenuTab").css("left", ""); //set to empty string
        //$(this).addClass("rShift"); //Not needed
    }
});
```

Note: this was tested with a local copy from your web.

Comment: Thank You! That worked. I was arriving at the solution that Robert McKee posted. But this is what I am going to do.